# Web-service Unit Testing performance

Tags: web-services, unit-testing

I'm  interested in knowing why calling a web-service method in succession executes faster (per call) the more calls there are or the more times it is executed; according to unit-testing execution timings...

```
public void Test_CardActivationWebService(string cardNo)
    {
        bool expected = true;
        bool actual = false;

        ServiceReference1.FDH_WSClient iclfdhws = new ServiceReference1.FDH_WSClient();
        ServiceReference1.CardActivationResponse response = iclfdhws.CardActivation(cardNo);
        actual = response;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: Care to share some sample code? Could it be some form of HTTP caching?

Comment: actually it's a very simple call...yes it could be some form of caching I guess; makes sense for sure.